# What is the out put of this code any why?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, printf

I have a function in C++, I know what the would be but why?

```
int c[5];
int* pc = c;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    c[i] = i*2;
}
*pc++;
printf("%d\n", pc-c );
```

Comment: Why don't you [run](http://ideone.com/OUYZgT) it?

Comment: output is `1` that is difference of addresses

Comment: I won't spoil the result, but the answer to the question "why" is "because of the code".

Comment: If you don't have the facility to run it yourself at present - what do ***you*** think the output would be and why? We can help you with any mistakes once you demonstrate what you have tried.

Comment: 1,2,4,6,8,10 is result

Comment: HINT: The trick here is to know whether *pc++ increments pc, or increments what pc points to.

Comment: Zero is printed while array is 1,2,4,6,8,10

Comment: [This](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) can be helpful too

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: No, it will print out `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Distance of addresses**

It seems the code is trying to show distance of pointer `pc` to `c` in memory addressing space.

1. `int* pc = c;` :  `pc` points to where `c` is pointing to. (Here `pc = c`)
2. `*pc++;` : `pc` increased one (Here `pc = c + 1` )
3. `pc - c` :  `pc - c` = `1` : **the distance** (number of integers between them)

```
 +------+------+------+------+------+
 |      |      |      |      |      |
 +------+------+------+------+------+
 ^      ^
 c      pc
```

*You can read about well-defined pointer arithmetic [expr.add] in §5.7 of C++ standard.*

Comment: Or it might be if doing that pointer arithmetic wasn't undefined behaviour, and I could have sworn passing a pointer into `%d` was as well.

Comment: @chris: At the time of the subtraction, `pc-c`, `pc` points to `c[1]`, so `pc-c` is 1. The argument passed to `printf` is not a pointer; it is a `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: @chris `pc-c` is a `ptrdiff_t` not a pointer, which may or may not match `%d`.

Comment: @chris: And why do you say the arithmetic is undefined? As far as I can see, it's staying within the array bounds.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, Ah right, not a pointer. And I'm being dumb with the arithmetic. For some reason, I was thinking it was subtracting a number (large enough to end up with a resulting address of 1). Your brain tricking you is a sucky feeling.

Answer (score 5):

There's a lot of garbage code going on. This is the only thing important for the print:

```
int c[5];              // c is a pointer
int* pc = c;           // pc points to the same thing as c.
pc++;                  // pc now points to one-past-where-c-points-to
printf("%d\n", pc-c ); // will print the pointer differences. 1.
```

Note that

```
*pc++;
```

actually means

```
*(pc++);
```

which is different from

```
(*pc)++;
```

When in doubt, always use brackets.

Comment: That reminded me this old quote from [a Dan Saks' article](http://www.dansaks.com/articles/1998-11%20Placing%20Data%20into%20ROM%20with%20Standard%20C.pdf) about operator precedence (emphasis mine): _“When in doubt about precedence, parenthesize. When certain about precedence, **parenthesize**. In either case, if you’re wrong, your program will still work and no one will be the wiser.”_ Assuredly a wise piece of advice :) (And even if you're not wrong, the next reader/maintainer of your code might be confused.)

Answer (score 0):

Output is `1` as it subtracts the addresses and returns the difference